# Getting Oauth Exceptions When trying to postback

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm trying to reply to a comment on wall/timeline. If i check the permissions withs i have with https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN (example) i get this returned:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "installed": 1,
         "read_stream": 1,
         "status_update": 1,
         "photo_upload": 1,
         "video_upload": 1,
         "email": 1,
         "create_note": 1,
         "share_item": 1,
         "publish_stream": 1,
         "publish_actions": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Which says i have publish_stream/actions - If i read the docs correctly then thats all i need? I can post new comments on a wall but not reply.

The exception i get is "(OAuthException) (#200) Requires publish_stream permission or Requires extended permission: publish_actions"

Do I need something else to allow me to reply to a post, it says i need the permissions i already have.

Thanks

EDIT:

Facebook SDK C#

```
public bool ReplyToPost(string objId, string message)
        {
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(GetAccessToken());

            IDictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            param.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("message", message));
            //744590031_10151761424915032 -- Test Obj.
            dynamic r = client.Post(string.Format("{0}/comments", objId), param);

            return true;
        }
```

I understand that once my app has been given permissions it should always have them?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to comment on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, are you posting the `objId` as `744590031_10151761424915032`?

Try calling the app with only the last part of the objId, e.g. `/10151761424915032/comments` and see if it works then.

Comment: hrmm.. Thats seems to have changed the response. Now im getting (OAuthException) (#200) User must have accepted TOS

Comment: Never seen that before. Is the user friends with the user who posted the comment via your app?

Comment: Its me, posting against' my own page. I have tested this using the Facebook test. The Access token generated by that seems to allow me to post. With the Facebook SDK once i have request my access_token, do i need to request a more powerful one? My Application has full permissions to do whatever it wants.

Comment: One access token is enough to post as it's valid for 24 hours. The TOS error usually means the user hasn't allowed access to the app...